# Color coding specific rows using longtabu and xcolor packages

Tags: tables, color, longtabu, arydshln

I am using the `longtabu` environment and trying to color code two rows in my table with the `\rowcolor{red}` command. I have loaded the relevant package `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. I searched for similar questions and it seems this is happening due to some incompatibility between the 2 `tabu` and the `xcolor` packages (github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/issues/1). I tried the following things but none of them work (my code is compiled smoothly) but the rows don't get color coded:

1) Used the `colortbl` package instead of `xcolor`

2) Used the command `\taburowcolors`

3) Used some of the macros mentioned in similar questions on tex.stackexchange

4) Changed the order of loading packages

I also tried to alternatively highlight my rows using dashed lines (instead of colors) by making use of the package `arydshnl`. However, this package is just incompatible with the `tabu` package and throws off errors such as undefined control sequence when I use the `\hdashline` command.

Please help me in either color coding my rows or using dashed lines with the above packages or some alternative packages. Thanks!

Comment: The tabu package is currently unmaintained and can cause some undesired outputs especially in combination with color. You might want to use longtable or xltabular instead.

Comment: see the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/

Comment: alternate packages can be advised provided u upload your table code which is compilable

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. I shall try xltabular or longtable and see if things work in my code

Comment: This is to inform you @leandriis  that tabularx works fine with xcolor. However, I hope that the experts fix longtabu over the long term. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Tabular}
]{
  colspec = {X[l]X[l]X[l]}, hlines,
  rowhead = 2, row{1-2} = {red8},
  hlines = {dashed},
}
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\ 
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]